# Payment error with Guernsey address

Tags: paypal

I have a shopping cart set up with an address_override and customers are getting errors when trying to buy froma Guernsey address.  I have a form on the website that collects Address, Town, County, Postcode and Country (all required fields) but when I customer tries to buy from Guernsey they get this error:

Please contact the merchant as the shipping address provided by the merchant is invalid, and the merchant has requested that your order must be shipped to that address.

Now I know it must be because the form has not been completed correctly somehow but what is wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

If you set 'address_override' as '1', the address specified with automatic fill-in variables overrides the PayPal member's stored address. Buyers see the addresses that you pass in, but they cannot edit them. PayPal does not show addresses if they are invalid or omitted.

For more information, see the link below.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0J0VU